# Hot-swap drive got new name. If I add it back to the `md` array and it gets renamed on reboot, will the array still work?

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, hotswap

One of the HDDs in my server's RAID config failed, so I took it out of the array and had the data center hot-swap it. They've done that, but now the new drive is `/dev/sdc` rather than `/dev/sda`. I suspect that if I reboot the server, it will be `/dev/sda` again, so I'm hesitant to add it back to the array as `/dev/sdc` because I don't want to lay a trap for myself to fall into on the next reboot. I'd just as soon not reboot the server if I don't need to (if I do need to, well, too bad for me).

If I add it as `/dev/sdc`, will there be a problem on reboot? Or is there some way to change the device name from `/dev/sdc` to `/dev/sda` without rebooting?

This is on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS. It's an `md` array ("Linux Software RAID"), where currently one of the devices (there are a couple of them) looks like this ("degraded" because I've removed the old `/dev/sda` from it):

```
# mdadm --detail /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
        Version : 00.90.03
  Creation Time : Sun Oct 11 21:07:54 2009
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 97536 (95.27 MiB 99.88 MB)
  Used Dev Size : 97536 (95.27 MiB 99.88 MB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 1
Preferred Minor : 0
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Thu Jun 30 09:31:16 2011
          State : clean, degraded
 Active Devices : 1
Working Devices : 1
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

           UUID : 496be7a5:ab9177ed:7792c71e:7dc17aa4
         Events : 0.112

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       17        0      active sync   /dev/sdb1
       1       0        0        1      removed
```

Comment: What array? If it's scanning UIDs it doesn't matter if it's sda or sdc

Comment: It's an `md` array ("Linux Software RAID"). All the device addition/removal and such refers to device names, but I don't know that that means it actually relies on them or... I've added the output of `mdadm --detail` on it to the question.

Comment: for md arrays mdadm scans all the disks (as defined in /etc/mdadm.conf) so it doesn't matter where are they, because it writes an ID into the header of the disk so it can reassemble the arrays.

Comment: Yes, thanks, check out the update on the question, I described that behavior and double-checked it worked.

Comment: Well...if I remember correctly for scsi drives you could send "scsi remove-single-device" to /proc/scsi/scsi and then readd the device with "scsi add-single-device", but I've never tried it and don't know the exact syntax for that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder instead (or in addition) of updating your question you might want to add your finding as an answer (and accept it), as this question is basically solved.

Comment: @DennisNolte - Thanks, done. Wow, I was such an SE newbie in 2011. :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's fine to go ahead and add it as `/dev/sdc`. Reading through [the kernel `md` documentation](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/md.txt), if the name changes on reboot, it doesn't matter. (Good design, that.) Here's why:

> ### Boot time autodetection of RAID arrays
>
> When md is compiled into the kernel (not as module), partitions of
>   type 0xfd are scanned and automatically assembled into RAID arrays.
>   This autodetection may be suppressed with the kernel parameter
>   "raid=noautodetect".  As of kernel 2.6.9, only drives with a type 0
>   superblock can be autodetected and run at boot time.
>
> The kernel parameter "raid=partitionable" (or "raid=part") means
>   that all auto-detected arrays are assembled as partitionable.

Although I didn't have `md` compiled into the kernel, my setup does the same thing as the above because it's auto-loading `mdadm` and the `mdadm.conf` is set up to scan all partitions for a superblock just like the kernel would:

```
# by default, scan all partitions (/proc/partitions) for MD superblocks.
# alternatively, specify devices to scan, using wildcards if desired.
DEVICE partitions
```

So it's fine to rebuild the array with `/dev/sdc`; the name probably will change to `/dev/sda` on reboot, but that won't cause any trouble if `md` is set up as above.